String array isn't valid argument for string array parameter VBA
In a program I've been working on, I had a function that returned a string array Function rtnStringArray() As String() The array returned would go on to be passed as an argument in another subroutine Sub useSrtArray(ByRef inArray As Variant)
For context, this program pulls data (strings) from cells in an excel sheet. I had a 2nd subroutine that counted the number of cells which had data for a specific column in order to properly allocate enough space in our array. For my recreated example this sub is irrelevant. Just note the excel document I'm working with has 4 relevant cells; A1 to A4, which contain string values.
Here is a short recreation of the problem:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    useArray (makeArray(4)) '4 because A1 to A4 is 4 cells, this is where I'd call the 3rd sub.
End Sub

Function makeArray(ByVal numRows As Integer) As String()
    Dim rtnArray() As String
    ReDim rtnArray(numRows - 1) As String
    Dim i As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentContent As String

    rowCount = 1
    i = 0
    currentContent = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowCount, 1).Value

    While currentContent <> ""
        rtnArray(i) = currentContent
        i = i + 1
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        currentContent = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowCount, 1).Value
    Wend
    
    makeArray = rtnArray
End Function

Sub useArray(ByRef inArray() As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(inArray) To UBound(inArray)
        MsgBox "INDEX: " & i & vbLf & "CONTENT: " & inArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub

This doesn't work. When you try to run it, you'll get "Compile Error: Type mismatch: Array or user-defined type expected" at useArray (makeArray(4))
To get this work I had to change the header of the sub to Sub useArray(ByRef inArray As Variant)
Can anyone explain?

Remove the parentheses around makeArray(4)

This is a very well asked question, btw, kudos for creating a reproducible example! As expected, this turns out to be a duplicate of another question.

In this context the parameter is a String. Only Variant can hold an array in VBA. This definition is only valid with Dim or other type definition context where the content of the array is predefined.

@Blackcat can you explain what you mean by "only Variant can hold an array"? Perhaps you're thinking of Array, which does return a Variant. But there are typed arrays in VBA.

Side suggestions: change all instances of Integer to Long. Then, it might be easier to use the 2D array you get from Range.Value (called on  a multicell range), instead of creating a 1D array.
